# Is there a way to do a parity check using bit shifting, and without using xor of a string with bits?

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, parity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        int iParity = 0;
        int bitmask = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
            switch (argv[1][i]) {
              case '0':
                if (iParity == 0)
                    iParity = 0;
                else
                    iParity = 1;
                break;
              case '1':
                if (iParity == 0)
                    iParity = 1;
                else
                    iParity = 0;
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("The parity is: %d", iParity);
    }
}
```

Basically I put the input directly into the execute line, like `./check 10010`, check is the name of the program, and afterwards I need to put binary number, and I need to parity check the number using bit shifting ( `<<` or `>>` ) and I SHOULD NOT use "xor" operator, is there a way to do that without really long code?

Comment: Count the bits and in the end see if the number is odd or even.

Comment: That was the first thought I had, but I HAVE TO use bit shifting

Comment: Count them using bit shifting... But I really don't see any reason to use any bitshifting when you have your number as a string.

Comment: The thing I forgot to mention, I have to use something like xor algorithm without actually using xor, so I just can't count no matter how. I tried to think about that too, like "Why do I need to do bitshifting" but I just think my teacher wants me dead, that's all

Comment: There is no way of doing it when you have **string** as input as bitshifts make no sense with strings.

Comment: ..unless your input is rather something like `./check 228`, and then you convert the string `"228"` into a number `228` and checking the parity of it. Well, you can also assume it is a binary number and use `strtoul` with base `2` to convert it as binary. But this is like scratching left ear with the right foot.

Comment: The idea I have is to try to do the copy of a number in a int, and try to bitshift the integer, it can be the case...maybe

Comment: @Genodan That is what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Indeed, I think it is a good idea

Comment: addition is equivalent to "xor" for the lowest bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      if(argc == 2){
          int iParity = 0;
          char c;
          int iSel = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++){
              c = argv[1][i] - '0';
              iSel = (iParity<<1) + c;
              switch(iSel){
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    iParity = 1;
                    break;
                case 0:
                case 3:
                    iParity = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
          }
        printf("Parity is: %d\n", iParity);
      }
  return 0;
}
```

Basically this is the solution my teacher told us in the out lesson, and yes, you had to convert a string index into a integer, and create a bit mask that works similar to a XOR operator, and that's pretty much it.

---

Addendum (by a commenter, scs):

The way the expression `iSel = (iParity<<1) + c` and the following `switch` statement work is that they implement the truth table for the XOR operator, like this:

| `iParity` | `c` | shift expression | XOR output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

In the end, the effect is the same as the much simpler

```
iParity = iParity ^ c;
```

Comment: Nothing against you, Genodan, but at first glance this looks like a terrible solution.  That expression `iSel = (iParity<<1) + c`, followed by that strange, 4-case `switch` statement, is a quite unnecessarily convoluted way to compute parity.  Thanks for posting it, though, and don't take the downvote personally: it's your teacher's solution I'm downvoting, not you.

Comment: Yeah you are right, that solution is really bad, in fact he said that the solution is bad, but he said us to do it in THAT way just so we can first see the problem resolved the bad way, and then he would show us the easy solution. I don't know about that, think it is a good method for teaching?

Comment: It's an eternal debate. There are plenty of exercises to go through on your way to full understanding, some of which aren't practical in the long run and will be forgotten once they've served their purpose. And then for any given artificial exercise, it's a matter of opinion whether its artificiality and other shortcomings are worth it in terms of the lesson learned.  Here, I'd say not, but obviously your instructor's opinion differs. (BTW, I thought better of the downvote and reversed it.)

Comment: The *actual lesson* embodied here — which is so subtle it's easy to miss entirely, and which I can't imagine a student thinking of (I certainly wouldn't have) — is that it, in a way, "creates a bit mask that works similar to a XOR operator", as you said.  If you don't mind, I'm going to add an addendum to your answer explaining this.  (I can't do it in this comment, because I'm going to need a table.)

Comment: For extra credit you could change the shift expression to `iSel = (iParity<<4) + c`, and then you could change the `case` labels to `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x10`, and `0x11`, and it would look that much more like an actual truth table.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 solutions without the use of exclusive or:

You can add the bit values directly from the string representation and use `&` to select the parity of the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        const char *s = argv[1];
        int iParity = 0 >> 0;  // required bitshift :)
        for (int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            iParity += p[i] == '1';
        }
        iParity &= 1;
        printf("The parity is: %d\n", iParity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your teacher might expect another approach, converting the number from text to an integer and computing the parity from its bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        // convert from base 2 text representation
        unsigned long number = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 2);
        int iParity = 0;
        while (number != 0) {
            iParity += number & 1;
            number = number >> 1;
        }
        iParity &= 1;
        printf("The parity is: %d\n", iParity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is another one with fewer steps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parity(unsigned long x) {
    int result = 0 >>007<< 0;  // zero, shaken not stirred
    while (x) {
        x &= x - 1;
        result = 1 - result;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        // convert from base 2 text representation
        unsigned long number = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 2);
        int iParity = parity(number);
        printf("The parity is: %d\n", iParity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No required bitshifts

Comment: Nice bit shift tho, really liked the implementation :D

Comment: I was going to post something like this, too.  If an instructor assigns a problem with a pointless constraint, go ahead and give them an answer that applies the constraint in a pointless way.  All's fair in love, war, and dangerously moronic C pedagogy.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive - but no XOR's

```
int verynaive(uint32_t v)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(v)
    {
        result += v & 1;
        v >>= 1;
    }
    return result & 1;
}
```

The fastest method I know is to use a lookup table.

```
int parity(uint32_t v)
{
    uint16_t lookup = 0b110100110010110;
    v ^= v >> 16;
    v ^= v >> 8;
    v ^= v >> 4;
    return (lookup >> (v & 0x0f)) & 1;
}
```

or a bit more naive

```
int func( uint32_t x ) 
{
    int32_t y;
    for ( y=0; x; y = !y )
    x ^= x & -x;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Both are using `xor` though

Comment: That's a nice method indeed, but "^" is for the xor operator, which I can't use, and furhtermore, we still didn't learn different type of integers like uint16/int32 etc.

Comment: @Genodan You can use `unsigned int` instead

Comment: @EugeneSh. added naive no xor function too

Comment: I believe right shifting signed integers can have implementation-defined behavior (e.g. for negative numbers) - I'd always go with unsigned instead

Comment: @MortenJensen where do you see any shifted **signed** numbers? Did you read the functions before commenting?

Comment: @0___________ nope, I did not read the veryNaiive function well enough to notice the shifting was done on `v`. I guess I auto-reacted from seeing the input-argument and return-type being signed. Thanks for correcting me and sorry for the FUD.